# Lifting of the addition operation from Haskell's Num class to dynamic values

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement my code based almost directly on a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pages 34-35). I am using Haskell's `Num` class instead of the user-defined `Number` class suggested in the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I want to focus on implementing addition over dynamic time-varying `Float` values, and subsequently addition over time-varying `Points`.

Listing 1 is my attempt. How do I get addition of points with time-varying coordinates to work properly?  My research requires a review of the code in that particular [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  As far as it is practical, I need to stick to the structure of the original code in the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf). In other words, what
do I need to add to **Listing 1** to overload (+) from `Num` to perform addition on time varying points?

```
module T where
type Time = Float
type Moving v = Time -> v

instance Num v => Num (Moving v) where
 (+) a b = \t -> (a t) + (b t)
 (-) a b = \t -> (a t) - (b t)
 (*) a b = \t -> (a t) * (b t)
 
-- tests for time varying Float values, seems OK
a,b::(Moving Float)
a = (\t -> 4.0)
b = (\t -> 5.0)
testA =  a 1.0
testAddMV1 = (a + b ) 1.0
testAddMV2 = (a + b ) 2.0

-- Point Class
class Num s => Points p s where
 x, y :: p s -> s
 xy :: s -> s -> p s


data  Point f = Point f f deriving Show


instance Num v => Points Point v where
 x (Point x1 y1) = x1
 y (Point x1 y1) = y1
 xy x1 y1 = Point x1 y1


instance Num v => Num (Point (Moving v)) where
 (+) a b = xy (x a + x b) (y a + y b)
 (-) a b = xy (x a - x b) (y a - y b)
 (*) a b = xy (x a * x b) (y a * y b)

-- Cannot get this to work as suggested in paper.
np1, np2 :: Point (Moving Float)
np1 = xy (\t -> 4.0 + 0.5 * t) (\t -> 4.0 - 0.5 * t)
np2 = xy (\t -> 0.0 + 1.0 * t) (\t -> 0.0 - 1.0 * t)

-- Error
-- testAddMP1 = (np1 + np2 ) 1.0
-- * Couldn't match expected type `Double -> t'
--   with actual type `Point (Moving Float)'
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: BTW it is very much a bad idea to give `Num` (or `Number`) instances to types like `Point`. Multiplication (not to speak of `abs` or `sqrt` etc.) does _not_ make physical sense on such types. The correct class is [`VectorSpace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace) instead, or possibly only [`AffineSpace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html#t:AffineSpace).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes of course., but my research requires a review of that particular paper. I need to stay a close as possible to the paper. I cannot use the `Number `class because the operation name will clash with `Num`from the Prelude. I want to avoid qualified imports.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne If your need is to follow the paper's code as closely as possible, and the paper defines its own `Number` class that is more appropriate than `Num` for this usage, why would you depart from your stated goal of following the research paper just because you don't like qualified imports?

Comment: @Ben I believe that either qualifying 'Num' import or renaming the operations in the `Number` class are needed to avoid name clashes.
 In my  [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72909159/9952780) I used renaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't really about the addition operation. You also can't write `np1 1.0` because this is a vector (I don't particularly like calling it that) whose components are functions. Whereas you try to use it as a function whose values are vectors.

What you're trying to express here is, "evaluate both the component-functions at this time-slice, and give me back the point corresponding to both coordinates". The standard solution (which I **don't** recommend, though) is to give `Point` a `Functor` instance. This is something the compiler can do for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data  Point f = Point f f
 deriving (Show, Functor)
```

And then you can write e.g.

```
fmap ($1) (np1 + np2)
```

Various libraries have special operators for this, e.g.

```
import Control.Lens ((??))

np1 + np2 ?? 1
```

Why is a functor instance a bad idea? For the same reason it's a bad idea to implement multiplication on points as component-wise multiplication<sup>†</sup>: it does not make sense physically. Namely, it depends on a particular choice of coordinate system, but the choice of coordinate frame is in principle arbitrary and should not affect the results. For addition it indeed does not affect the result (disregarding float inaccuracy), but for multiplication or arbitrary function-mapping it can massively affect the result.

A better solution is to just not use "function-valued points" in the first place, but instead point-valued functions.

```
np1, np2 :: Moving (Point Float)
np1 = \t -> xy (4.0 + 0.5 * t) (4.0 - 0.5 * t)
np2 t = xy (0.0 + 1.0 * t) (0.0 - 1.0 * t)
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually a functor instance is a less bad idea than a `Num` instance. The particular operation `fmap ($1)` *is* in fact equivariant under coordinate transformation. That's because point-evaluation of functions is a [linear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map). To properly express this, you could make `Point` an endofunctor in the [category of linear maps](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Would it be fair to say that the code in **Listing 1** could not be run without `DeriveFunctor ` or some more modern Haskell extensions?  The original code is from 2003.

Comment: But of course functors were in Haskell98 already, you just needed to write the instances by hand back then. (Or else you could always have a custom `fmap`-ish function specific to `Point`.)

Answer (score 0):

I include a renaming approach in **Listing 2** and a qualified import approach in **Listing 3** .

**Listing 2** contains code that I believe is reasonably close to the [original code](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It was necessary rename the operations in `Number` by appending (!). This avoids a clash with the operations in Prelude `Num` class. I believe that there were two errors in the [original code](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9804&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  The most serious is in the `instance  Number (Moving Float)` where the same operation symbols are used on the left and right of the equations (e.g. +). The compiler has no way to distinguish these operations. The other error is a syntax error `instance Number v => (Point v)` there is no class name after `=>`. In sort the original code will not run, which was the motivation behind the question.

**Listing 2**

```
module T where
type Time = Float
type Moving v = Time -> v

class Number a where
 (+!), (-!), (*!) :: a -> a -> a
 sqr1, sqrt1 :: a -> a

-- Define Number operations in terms of Num operations from Prelude
-- Original code does not distinguish between these operation and will not compile.
instance  Number (Moving Float) where
 (+!) a b = \t -> (a t) + (b t)
 (-!) a b = \t -> (a t) - (b t)
 (*!) a b = \t -> (a t) * (b t)
 sqrt1 a = \t -> sqrt (a t)
 sqr1 a = \t -> ((a t) * (a t))

data Point f = Point f f deriving Show

class Number s => Points p s where
 x, y :: p s -> s
 xy :: s -> s -> p s
 dist :: p s -> p s -> s
 dist a b = sqrt1 (sqr1 ((x a) -! (x b)) +! sqr1 ((y a) -! (y b)))

instance Number v => Points Point v where
 x (Point x1 y1) = x1
 y (Point x1 y1) = y1
 xy x1 y1 = Point x1 y1

-- Syntax error in instance header in original code.
instance Number (Point (Moving Float)) where
 (+!) a b = xy (x a +! x b) (y a +! y b)
 (-!) a b = xy (x a -! x b) (y a -! y b)
 (*!) a b = xy (x a *! x b) (y a *! y b)
 sqrt1 a =  xy (sqrt1 (x a)) (sqrt1 (y a))
 sqr1 a =  xy (sqr1 (x a)) (sqr1 (y a))


mp1, mp2 ::  Point (Moving Float)
mp1  = (xy (\t -> 4.0 + 0.5 * t) (\t -> 4.0 - 0.5 * t)) 
mp2  = xy (\t -> 0.0 + 1.0 * t) (\t -> 0.0 - 1.0 * t)
movingDist_1_2 = dist mp1 mp2
dist_at_2 = movingDist_1_2 2.0 -- gives 5.83
```

**Listing 3** uses a qualified import as suggested by [ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450128/ben). Note we need an additional instance to define the operations in the `Number` class using the `Num` class.

**Listing 3**

```
module T where
import qualified Prelude as P

type Time = P.Float
type Moving v = Time -> v

class Number a where
 (+), (-), (*) :: a -> a -> a
 sqr, sqrt:: a -> a

instance Number P.Float where
 (+) a b =  a P.+ b
 (-) a b =  a P.- b
 (*) a b =  a P.* b
 sqrt a =  P.sqrt a
 sqr a = a P.* a
  
instance  Number (Moving P.Float) where
 (+) a b = \t -> (a t) + (b t)
 (-) a b = \t -> (a t) - (b t)
 (*) a b = \t -> (a t) * (b t)
 sqrt a = \t -> sqrt (a t)
 sqr a = \t -> ((a t) * (a t))

data Point f = Point f f deriving P.Show

class Number s => Points p s where
 x, y :: p s -> s
 xy :: s -> s -> p s
 dist :: p s -> p s -> s
 dist a b = sqrt (sqr ((x a) - (x b)) + sqr ((y a) - (y b)))

instance Number v => Points Point v where
 x (Point x1 y1) = x1
 y (Point x1 y1) = y1
 xy x1 y1 = Point x1 y1

instance Number (Point (Moving P.Float)) where
 (+) a b = xy (x a + x b) (y a + y b)
 (-) a b = xy (x a - x b) (y a - y b)
 (*) a b = xy (x a * x b) (y a * y b)
 sqrt a =  xy (sqrt (x a)) (sqrt (y a))
 sqr a =  xy (sqr (x a)) (sqr (y a))

mp1, mp2 ::  Point (Moving P.Float)
mp1  = xy (\t -> 4.0 + (0.5 * t)) (\t -> 4.0 - (0.5 * t))
mp2  = xy (\t -> 0.0 + (1.0 * t)) (\t -> 0.0 - (1.0 * t))
movingDist_1_2 = dist mp1 mp2
dist_at_2 = movingDist_1_2 2.0
```